# How to format regression output if year-quarter is a variable?

Tags: stata

I am using Stata and generated dummies for year quarter for regression by: i.yq

I have already fixed yq using format tq, and browsing the data confirms that it looks fine. However, it still shows up as numbers in my regression output. [Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU2xh.png)

For example, instead of showing as 200XqX just as it does in the dataset, it appears as number ABC

Comment: An inelegant way to accomplish this is to assign value labels to the `yq` variable, where the value labels contain the date-formatted values. Perhaps others will have a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code expanding on @Brie's suggestion:

```
clear
set obs 25
gen t = _n-1
format t %tq
expand 100
gen y = rnormal()

local format: format t
clonevar tlab = t
levelsof tlab, local(time)
foreach t of local time {
    local lab: display `format' `t',
    lab define tlab `t' `lab', modify
}
lab val tlab tlab

reg y i.tlab, fvlabel
```

Comment: The comma after `t' will not cause an error, but it is unnecessary.